# c++ can you name child windows to make their handle static?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, handles

I've looked everywhere for an answer, and hopefully it's because it's not been answered rather than my search terms lacking in detail. I know how to get and work with handles, I'm just asking a general question.

Every program I have made using MFC has the window handle #32770, but all other windows like edit boxes and such all have dynamic handles, so every time you open the program it's handle is different. How does the main program get it's handle, and is it possible to give any window a static name so that enumwindows or winspy++/similar tools aren't  repeatedly necessary.

Comment: You're confusing handles with class names.

Comment: All window handles are dynamic. However a child window can have a unique numeric id. A top-level window can instead have a menu line.

Answer (score 1):

Window handles are always dynamic. You manage them by saving their values at the creation moment or using special win api functions, in case of MFC you use `CWnd` class or rather classes derived from it. You can use `FindWindow`, if you want to find some external to your application window by name/class. In your dialogs you can use `GetDlgItem` to find window of your control using its `id`.